# Создать словарь с помощью enumerate

Tags: python, dict

Можно ли создать список словарей с помощью enumerate такого вида:

```
[{"id": 0, "animal": 'snail'}, {"id": 1, "animal": 'fish'}, {"id": 2, "animal": 'cow'}
```

Знаю, что можно сделать так:

```
animals = ['snail', 'fish', 'cow']
a = {animal: it for it, animal in enumerate(animals)}
b = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}
```

Но с помощью такого кода получается словарь:

```
{0: 'snail', 1: 'fish', 2: 'cow'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
animals = ['snail', 'fish', 'cow']
result = [{"id": n, "animal": animal} for n, animal in enumerate(animals)]
# [{'id': 0, 'animal': 'snail'}, {'id': 1, 'animal': 'fish'}, {'id': 2, 'animal': 'cow'}]
```